# Get exacly a specific line after a match in a file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a log file with this pattern

```
Time = 100

GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.2174470886, Final residual = 0.01001676933, No Iterations 1
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.02692910633, Final residual = 0.0004864615367, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.005753534485, Final residual = 0.0001502172182, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.001526301953, Final residual = 5.384448346e-05, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0004529702305, Final residual = 1.80754637e-05, No Iterations 1
time step continuity errors : sum local = 2.722585271, global = 0.09763545089, cumulative = 0.09763545089
ExecutionTime = 27.35 s  ClockTime = 31 s

Time = 101

GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.04799119366, Final residual = 0.002390404161, No Iterations 1
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.02803010067, Final residual = 0.0009371130484, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.007210353379, Final residual = 0.0002494798057, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.002410795933, Final residual = 0.000116871876, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0007431402835, Final residual = 1.649739876e-05, No Iterations 3
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0003489407136, Final residual = 1.262095062e-05, No Iterations 1
time step continuity errors : sum local = 0.7142966337, global = -0.1125594528, cumulative = -0.01492400189
ExecutionTime = 41.42 s  ClockTime = 45 s

Time = 102
```

The line after `Time =` is always `Iterations 1` and I want to get get that line. I have tried these ideas:

With grep, if I write `grep -A 2 "Time =" test.txt`, it will show

```
Time = 100

GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.2174470886, Final residual = 0.01001676933, No Iterations 1
```

and

```
ExecutionTime = 27.35 s  ClockTime = 31 s

Time = 101
```

If I use awk like `cat test.txt | awk '/Time/{getline;getline;print}'` it will show

```
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.2174470886, Final residual = 0.01001676933, No Iterations 1
Time = 101
Time = 102
```

Those `Time = 101` and `Time = 102` are the two lines after `ExecutionTime`.

Briefly, I only want to get the first non-empty line after `Time =` which I know it is always `Iterations 1`. How can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be absolutely sure that you print the first line ending in `No Iterations 1` after a `Time = ...` line, you could use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '/^Time =/ {f=1} /No Iterations 1$/ && f {f=0; print}' test.txt
```

This `awk` command has two rules (`{ ... }`).

- The first one is processed if the line matches the regular expression `^Time =`, i.e. it starts with the string `Time =`. In this rule, we simply set a flag `f` to `1` to indicate that the "start line" of the pattern was found.
- The next one is processed if the line matches the regular expression `No Iterations 1$`, i.e. it *ends* with the string `No Iterations 1`, *and* we have previously found the `Time =`-line. If both conditions are met, the line is printed, and the flag `f` reset so that we don't print any of the following lines that end in `No Iterations 1`.

A more "relaxed" variant, which simply prints the first non-empty line after the `Time = ...` statement (not checking if it contains the `No Iterations 1` pattern) would be:

```
awk '/^Time =/ {f=1; next} NF>0 && f {f=0; print}' test.txt
```

This simply looks if the flag `f` is set, and that `NF`, the "number of fields" (or columns, if you will) in the line is larger than zero. Note that here, we have to add a `next` command in the first rule to skip execution to the next line, as otherwise the `NF>0`-rule would already be processed for the `Time =`-lines, effectively printing only these.

For your example, both print:

```
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.2174470886, Final residual = 0.01001676933, No Iterations 1
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.04799119366, Final residual = 0.002390404161, No Iterations 1
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I am curious to know how that is achieved. The cyntax is rather odd... I appreciate if you explain that in the answer.